# Group data based on count of duplicate values in a certain column

Tags: excel, count

I have an excel sheet that is organized as follows:

```
COL1   COL2
1      30   
2      30
3      29 
4      12
5      12
6      12
```

In the above, as you can see, values are being repeated in COL2. I need to group these values count and then place them in separate workbooks. So, for example, the output should be

```
Total Records: 2
1, 30, ......
2, 30, ......

Total Records: 1
3, 29, ......

Total Records: 3
4, 12, ......
5, 12, ......
6, 12, ......
```

Once that is calculate, I need them exported into separate excel sheets.

Can someone please help me figure out the best approach to do this? How may this be done in Excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create pivot tables to do this. Create one pivot table for all your data, then duplicate and separate one pivot per value in Column 2. Put each of those pivots in the new work sheets as you need. If you need help with setting the pivots up, please take a look at [this site](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/excel-pivot-tables.htm).

This can also be done in VBA, if this is a large task or something you will need to do on a regular basis. Since you didn't ask for the VBA, I'll assume for now that you mean to do this manually.

Comment: Hell Gaffi, thanks for your answer. I have implemented the solution in .NET where I read in the Excel sheet using OLEDB. Then, I use LINQ to manipulate it. However, the whole method is very crude to say the least, and I am looking for a much cleaner option. Yes, this needs to be done on regular basis.

I would look into pivot tables. Thanks for the info. There is no way this can be done using regular Excel grouping or other like functions????

Thanks again, appreciate it.

Comment: You might be able to use the subtotals functionality (look under the data menu, where you'll also find the pivot tables), but I think (could be wrong on this) the data must be presorted, which your example appears to be.

Comment: As a follow up, since you did mention .NET, you may also want to look [here](http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/vb-net-and-excel/). This belongs to the SO user [Siddharth Rout](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout) who is a wizard when it comes this stuff!

Comment: The link above is not dead, but it is redirecting... now available [here](http://bit.ly/ZDwAUr).